# electric-indent-mode breaks my Python code

Tags: emacs, elisp, python-mode

I have this code on Emacs with `python-mode` enabled:

```
def func(a):
    if a:
        return True
    return False
```

When I move the cursor between `return False` and `def func(` the code is automatically indented, breaking it:

```
def func(a):
    if a:
        return True
        return False #Oops!
```

I came to know that this happens because of `electric-indent-mode`, a minor global mode. However, I tried to turn it off, but the issue remains.

The elisp code that I use is this:

```
(defun disable-electric-indent ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'electric-indent-functions)
       (list (lambda (arg) 'no-indent))))
```

and this how my `python-mode-hook` looks:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
              (flyspell-prog-mode)
              (auto-complete-mode)
              (nlinum-mode)
              (toggle-truncate-lines t)
              (setq autopair-handle-action-fns
                    (list 'autopair-default-handle-action 'autopair-python-triple-quote-action))
              (centered-cursor-mode)
              (auto-indent-mode)
              (autopair-mode)
              (column-marker-1 80)
              (flycheck-mode)
              (setq ac-auto-start 2)
              (disable-electric-indent) ;; esto deberia hacer que emacs deje de romper las pelotas con el codigo en python
              (jedi:setup)))
```

If I turn off `auto-indent-mode` this behavior stops (however, I don't get auto indentation, glol).

my emacs version: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.1) of 2013-04-29 on eric`

**EDIT**: I'm using the `python` package (the built-in Python's flying circus support for Emacs, you know) in its version `0.24.2`, according to melpa. Maybe I should remove it and use `python-mode` package in its version 6.0.10?

Comment: If referring to python-mode.el, try current trunk via bazaar, bzr branch lp:python-mode, resp. download from https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: Actually, this behavior is gone if I use ```python-mode.el```. I have some minor issues with that package now, but is nothing critical that I cannot fix, thanks!

(please your comment as an answer please!)

Comment: Get used to `C-j` instead of `RET`, or bind `RET` to `newline-and-indent`.  That gives you automatic indentation.

Comment: @JorgeArayaNavarro Even with minor issues, don't hesitate to file a report/request at `https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode`. This will help us and others.

Answer (score 3):

You might like to try

```
(defun my-disable-electric-indent ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'electric-indent-mode) nil))
```

Comment: Obviously, you additionally need to call this function.  Or just add the `set` to your `python-mode-hook`.  But if you still see the problem when `electric-indent-mode` is nil, then the problem is most likely not in electric-indent-mode.  Probably in `auto-indent-mode` instead.

Comment: @mzuther is the problem electric-indent-mode or auto-indent-mode?

Comment: If the code snippet solved his problem, then the problem was with `electric-indent-mode`, I think.

Comment: @Sampath Kumar Rao: I haven't got `auto-indent-mode` installed, so it's definitely the `electric-indent-mode`. If it matters, my Emacs version is 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32).

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a bug, it should never be indented as your example shows.

Beside would expect several conflicts from an auto-indent-mode, consider it a bad thing with python-mode. Not in your example, but at other places there is indent just a choice. Auto-indent can't know where to indent then.
As newline-and-indent, it will select the outmost probably, which will be wrong in some cases. That might turn nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I just migrated to `python-mode.el` and leave the code to turn off the `electric-indent-mode` :)

Comment: Congratulation! BTW several electric features are offered there. When feeling at home with the common proceeding, try `py-electric-backspace` -when editing lists for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `(setq electric-indent-inhibit t)` in any mode when reindentation is not supposed to happen, such as python mode. It is the official way to do it, as document in the `C-h v electric-indent-inhibit`.